# Adding a field specific error from the controller in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have some complex validation going on with my symfony form, and I need to be able to assign an error to a specific field from my controller. Right now, I have global errors working like this:

```
$error = new formerror("There is an error with the form");
$form->addError($error);
```

But that creates a global error, not one bound to a specific field.

Is there a way to throw an error on a specific field from my controller?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Thanks to some help over IRC (thanks @fkrauthan!) I came up with an answer.

Every field in SF2 is actually an instance of form. What you need to do is access the form object of the field, and add then error onto it. Thankfully, symfony provides a method to get an embedded form/field.

Heres my code:

```
$error = new FormError("There is an error with the field");
$form->get('field')->addError($error);
```

As some people have pointed out, you will need to include the FormError class at the top of your file:
`use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;`

Comment: Stack overflow doesn't let you accept your own answer for the first 2 days.

Comment: what do I need to include as a USE on top in order to be able to use formerror class properly?

Comment: You don't actaully need to use the 'use' statement. You just need to pass the full qualifier after new.
    $error = new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError("There is an error with the field");

Comment: This is still true for Symfony 4 in 2019

Comment: @JonathanHolvey I attempted this in SF4 and it is continuing with the controller after adding in this error. Do you need to return or anything?

Comment: @Chris The controller will continue, but the form should now be marked invalid.

Comment: Still works Symfony 6